# Problems with boot "Windows Boot Manager boot failed"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1, and I am having problems with booting into Windows and Ubuntu.

First what happened was that I was unable to load into ubuntu. It would say something like 'ubuntu boot failed' then go straight to windows bypassing grub2. I did a live USB and boot repair and got this message here:

```
An error occurred during the repair.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12299126/


In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com

Locked-ESP detected. You may want to retry after creating a /boot/efi partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option of [Boot Repair].
```

I restarted my computer then grub seemed to work again and I was able to boot into Ubuntu. Now though when I selected Windows from the grub it just returned me back to grub. I vaguely remembered having this problem before and it said to replace the bootmgfw.efi in /boot/Microsoft/Boot which I did but it did not work. I put Windows first in my Bios but that didn't work (same thing with the grub screen), so I ran boot repair again. I now got this message:

```
An error occurred during the repair.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12307416/

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com

You can now reboot your computer.


The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
```

Now when I start my computer, it says "Windows Boot Manager boot failed". Will you guys be able to help? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both your Boot Repair output files indicate the presence of backup files created by Boot Repair -- that is, the utility copied the Windows files (such as `bootmgfw.efi` to another name and replaced the original files with duplicate copies of GRUB. Boot Repair sometimes does this to work around bugs with certain EFIs, which tend to ignore or forget the EFI boot order variables. Recent versions of Boot Repair will only do this if you explicitly tell it to do so in the Advanced menu, but older versions over-applied this ugly hack of a fix (to an equally ugly bug) to all repairs. Thus, it's not clear to me whether you're using an older Boot Repair or you told it to apply this workaround. Either way, the workaround is likely at least part of the problem, since your `grub.cfg` file provides pointers to the original Microsoft boot loader filenames, not their backups. This might have happened if you used `update-grub` in Ubuntu to create a new `grub.cfg` file after applying the Boot Repair workaround. (Boot Repair itself should create a `grub.cfg` that points to the backed-up file.)

Your second Boot Repair output lacks the backup files for the main Windows boot loader file (`bootmgfw.efi`). I assume this is because you modified or copied this file (you wrote that you "replace[d] the bootmgfw.efi in /boot/Microsoft/Boot," but you didn't specify what you replaced it with). Depending on what you did, this might make recovery more difficult.

Your `efibootmgr` output (lines 1689-1700 in your second Boot Repair output) indicates that your computer is configured to boot the Windows entry -- but as the Windows boot loader has probably been replaced by GRUB, a boot through GRUB to Ubuntu would not be surprising.

In sum, your system is in a tangled mess of a state. For recovery, I recommend:

1. ***Back up your ESP!*** The [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is normally mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu. It's a FAT partition that holds boot loader files, and to enable recovery from future mis-steps that might make matters even worse, backing it up is in order. Fortunately, it's relatively small, and a file-level backup (made with `cp` or `tar`, for instance) should suffice. Copy the ESP to a FAT USB flash drive for greatest flexibility -- you may even be able to boot using the flash drive in a pinch.
2. If you're using an old copy of Boot Repair, trash it and get the latest version instead.
3. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a boot medium from the files. The point is to have rEFInd as an emergency system; you should be able to boot Ubuntu and/or Windows from rEFInd, should things go south.
4. Launch Boot Repair, enter the Advanced menu, and select the option to restore backed-up files. This may get things working again. OTOH, there's a chance that this will make matters worse -- that's where the backup and rEFInd may become helpful.
5. If the preceding doesn't help, boot using the rEFInd boot medium. It should show you options to boot both Linux and Windows -- possibly multiple options for both. Try each of them and see if you can get into either or both OSes. You may be able to use this to recover from a disaster (say by restoring your ESP backup) or to gather further diagnostic information. For instance, if you select a Windows icon and it boots GRUB, then that's a clear indication that the replacement I described earlier has occurred and has not been fixed. Note that a problem at this point could take many forms, so I can't provide explicit instructions without writing a small book. You'll have to wing it or post back with details for more help.
6. If you can't get into Windows at this point (via either a fixed GRUB or rEFInd), then you'll need to restore your Windows boot loader using Windows tools. This is a topic best covered in a Windows forum. Be sure to specify that you're booting in EFI mode; there's a lot of inapplicable BIOS-mode advice still floating around, and people who know only BIOS mode offering inapplicable advice. Chances are that recovering the Windows boot loader will cause the computer to boot straight to Windows. You can use the rEFInd external medium to boot back into Ubuntu and then use `efibootmgr` to restore the Ubuntu boot loader to the default, or use Boot Repair to re-install GRUB, or install rEFInd to your hard disk by installing its PPA or Debian package, as you see fit.
7. Once you get everything working, make a fresh backup of your ESP, so that you can restore it to a working state if and when new problems arise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! I actually realized I had a Windows Recovery CD and I decided just to use that which somehow got everything to work (even though it threw up error messages). I'll keep what you said in mind though to hopefully fix it at some point (or I might just backup my data and delete the ubuntu partition before reinstalling it!) Thanks for all the advice though! I really am grateful!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the "Locked-ESP detected" error seemed to be caused by my partitions being mounted. (I was running Boot-Repair from a Ubuntu Live USB, as explained in the 2nd option of the [Boot-Repair wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)).

Once I unmounted the partitions (I used gParted, right-clicking on every partition and choosing unmount), Boot-Repair succeeded in repairing my system (using Recommended Repair).

See also [this article](http://bartssolutions.blogspot.be/2016/12/windows-10-update-broke-my-ubuntu-linux.html).